# Check value in TextField with NSDictionary Objective C (for Login)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'am a super a super rookie in IOS. I am doing a login feature.  When the login in button is pressed, the APP shall check the text from storage. Then it should change to the second VC if check status return true. I currently have a ViewController to ViewController segue with identifier. I tried the perform segue with identifier but it doesn't work.(Doesn't change scene and shows no alert.)

Here is the login Page.
    #import

```
@interface LoginPage : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
- (IBAction)LoginTapped:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)SignupTapped:(id)sender;
@end
```

the login.m

```
#import "LoginPage.h"
#import "Home.h"
@implementation LoginPage

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)LoginTapped:(id)sender {

    NSMutableDictionary *infodictionary =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [infodictionary setObject:@"1" forKey:@"rose"];
    [infodictionary setObject:@"2" forKey:@"cathy"];
    [infodictionary setObject:@"3" forKey:@"corey"];
    if ([_passwordField.text isEqualToString:[infodictionary objectForKey: _usernameField.text]]){
 //       Home *home = [[Home alloc] init];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToHome" sender:self];
    }

}

- (IBAction)SignupTapped:(id)sender {
    NSString *_NAME = [NSString alloc];
    NSString *_PASS = [NSString alloc];
    _NAME=  _usernameField.text;
    _PASS = _passwordField.text;
       }
@end
```

the stimulator gives me terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
2016-02-07 05:39:49.437 project_feature_login[8249:941926] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x7fb5f9c98300> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key passwordField.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102b18f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102592deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102b18b89 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010215fa6b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010305004c -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010327da71 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a59a80 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010327c454 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000103056c16 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000103057542 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001030578a0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000103058013 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000102f3151c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000102f31c05 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000102f434a5 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000102ebd396 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000102ec39c3 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1750
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000102ec0ba3 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000105870784 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000105870af2 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a45011 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a3af3c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a3a3f3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a39e08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000102ec04f5 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000102ec530d UIApplicationMain + 171
    26  project_feature_login               0x0000000102094a6f main + 111
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010523c92d start + 1
    28  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

Seeking for Help!!!!

Comment: The stacktrace doesn't appear to involve any of your code.  I would hazard a guess that the issue is in the interface (NIB).

Comment: Can you make sure, your IBActions and IBOutlets are connected properly?

Comment: @Vishnugondlekar I created a cocoa file and put the IBAction there.

Comment: @Vishnugondlekar Should I just add them to the default Viewcontroller?

Comment: Problem arises when you press signup button?

Comment: @ShehzadAli I currently haven't started the signup. Just declared a dictionary to check if the user info is correct.

Comment: Try using self.passwordField.text instead of _passwordField.text while verifying your if condition. Also check the IBOutlet connection of passwordField in Interface Builder. Class set for that UIViewController in interface must be LoginPage.

Comment: @ShehzadAli thanks sooooo much!!! It works!  I didn't connect the IBOutlet successfully!!!

Comment: I am going to write it in answer and please accept it :)

Comment: @ShehzadAli sure haha

Comment: haha happy coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `self.passwordField.text` instead of `_passwordField.text` while verifying your if condition. Also check the IBOutlet connection of **passwordField** in **Interface Builder**. Class set for that UIViewController in interface must be LoginPage